# Post string variable to url after mail has been sent

Tags: javascript, php, email, post, sendmail

i would really need your help. Am developing a contact/enquiry form in my website and will like the visitor to be redirected  and to see their name in the thank you page after his request has been sent to my email.

I have a php processing the mail()function but i need to invoke a javascript or something similar to post his name string to the thank you page after the mail has been sent.

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_dept = $_POST['department'];
$field_inquiry = $_POST['inquiry'];

$mail_to = 'customersupport@domain.com';
$field_contact = 'contactform@domain.com';
$subject = 'New Email Arrived '.$field_name;

$body_message .= 'name: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'Department: '.$field_dept."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_inquiry."\n";


$headers = 'From: '.$field_contact."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_contact."\r\n";


$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
?>
```

I used to have this php code that redirects to the thank you page but it doesn't post the $field_name

```
if($mail_status) {header( "Location: thankyou.html" );} else {print "We encountered an error sending your mail"; }
```

Can any one help me with a replacement or JavaScript that will redirect and also post $field_name to the thankyou.html after the mail must have been sent by php. 
The complete php/javascript coding will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: so don't redirect to a .html file. just `include()` a .php file and set some variables in it. e.g. `<?php echo "Thanks, $field_name"`

Comment: can post method be used instead of get?

Answer (score 0):

Just send the name via get url parameter:

```
header( "Location: thankyou.php?name={$field_name}" );

//thankyou.php

echo "hello" . $_GET['name'];
```

Comment: $field_url="https :// www. domain.com"  i want to now add a url, how can i add the $field_url alone to be transferred using get. am getting a Not Acceptable error when it loads

Comment: @frankie you need to use `urlencode` function, eh `&url=" . urlencode($field_url)`